# How to disable Services on run- or startuptime in Spring?

Tags: spring

In our standalone Spring 3.1 Application we divided the Business logic from a Monitoring Swing View strictly. The view get its information by implementing an `EventListener` interface.

To disable the UI it would be enough to "remove" all the `@Services` on the UI Beans so that the UI Class that implements this EventListner get not Injected by the Business logic.

But how to do this?

This Example gives a small Oerview of our classes:

```
@Service
public class UI extends JFrame implements EventListener {
    @PostConstruct
    public void setup() {
        // Do all the Swing stuff
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBusinessLogicUpdate(final State state) {
        // Show the state on the ui
    }
}

@Service
public class Businesslogic {
    @Autowired
    public List<EventListener>  eventListeners;

    public void startCalculation() {

        do {
            // calculate ...
            for (final EventListener listener : this.eventListeners) {
                eventlistener.onBusinessLogicUpdate(currentState);
            }
        }
        while(/* do some times */);
    }
}

public class Starter {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ApplicationContext context = // ...;

        if(uiShouldBedisabled(args)) {
            // remove the UI Service Bean
        }

        context.getBean(Businesslogic.class).startCalculation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your description you want to disable these beans on startup, not on any arbitrary point in time - which is much harder.

## `@Profile`

The easiest approach is to use [Spring `@Profile`s](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/) (available since 3.1), selectively enabling and disabling beans:

```
@Service
@Profile("gui")
public class UI extends JFrame implements EventListener
```

Now you need to tell your application context which profile you want use. If `gui` profile is activated, `UI` bean will be included. If not - Spring will skip that class. There are various ways to change the profile name, e.g.:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
if(!uiShouldBedisabled(args)) {
    ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("gui");
}
ctx.scan("com.example");
ctx.refresh();
```

## Separate JAR

Split your application to two JARs - your business logic and GUI. If you don't want to start GUI, just remove `gui.jar` from CLASSPATH (yes, this isn't possible at runtime, but during build/deployment time).

## Two `applicationContext.xml` files

If your application starts from XML, create `applicationContext.xml` and `applicationContext-gui.xml`. Obviously all GUI beans are in the latter. You don't have to specify them manually, just put GUI beans in different package and add clever `<context:component-scan/>`.